# Is there a way to get maven version during a plugin MOJO execution?

Tags: maven, plugins

I am trying to build a maven plugin which captures basic maven metadata (maven version, java version used by maven during build). How do I get this data inside the plugin ?

Comment: What do you have so far? What about https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html ?